# Drop columns from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a .csv file data being imported into mysql table. What I like to do everytime I run the code I would like to DROP all of the column and the data and REPLACE it with the updated .csv content.

```
   $affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
     //HERE I do need additional code to drop column data from $databasetable similar to following
  /*------------------------------------------*/
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '$databasetable'

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$databasetable` (
          Column names1
          Column name 2
          .
     ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
  /*------------------------------------------*/


     LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
     LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator));
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused by what you're asking here.

Typically, using DROP in reference to a column means to remove the column from the table.

Also, are there columns of data in this table that you want to keep? That's going to change the answer as well.

Comment: Let me elaborate on this. If you want to keep the table structure (retain all columns), but get rid of the data, the "TRUNCATE {tablename}" command will work.

If you need to get rid of a column completely (as in that column no longer exists on that table), it would be "ALTER TABLE {tablename} DROP COLUMN {columnname}". At least, that's how it's done in MYSQL.

Comment: P. Gearman  Thank you for the reply. I am sorry for not being clear about my question. I esentially want to remove $databasetable content everytime this script is executed (Columns and rows in this table.

Comment: Seeing that comment ^ seems like what you're looking for is a trigger or an event.

Comment: If you want to remove content, use `DELETE FROM`. If you want to drop a column, that is a horse of an entirely different color.

Comment: I am looking something like this but I am getting an error DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '$databasetable'

Comment: If you DROP the table, what are you inserting the CSV data into? Remember, DROP gets rid of what you tell it to DROP.

Comment: P. Gearman if I manually drop the table from my database using PHPMySQL and run my script fields are generated and data is dumped into right fileds. I just want to be able to keep the table and get rid of what is inside the table including columns and data. See edits on my question. Thanks

Comment: @CyberFla - As mentioned, DROP TABLE gets rid of the entire table, so yes that does what you are asking ie *"...get rid of what is inside the table including columns and data"*. Though unless the columns change, you could simply TRUNCATE the table instead. Without knowing the use case, it is hard to say if you really need to DROP the table or not...

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is **TRUNCATE** the Table in Question. That is to remove all the Data inside the Table but not Delete the Table itself, right?
So, here is 1 Tip:

```
<?php 
    //FIRST TRUNCATE (REMOVE OLD DATA IN THE TABLE $databasetable
    $stmt      = $db->prepare("TRUNCATE TABLE {$databasetable}");
    $tblEmpty  = $stmt->execute();

    //NOW, ONCE THE TABLE'S BEEN TRUNCATED; YOU MAY CONTINUE WITH THE NEW "INSERTS"...
    if($tblEmpty){
        // INSERT THE DATA FROM THE CSV...
    }

    //...
    //...
    // MORE CODE HERE...
```

Comment: Poiz, Yes to your question. I want to keep the table but remove all of the data inside. Correct me if i am wrong: Truncate only removes the data not the column names right?

Comment: Exactly... Truncate will simple delete the records (Data) but never mess with the Table Definition (Column Names, etc). However, if you truncate an Auto-Incremented Table; the value of the Auto-Incremented Field/Column does not become 0 or 1. The Auto-Incremented Field retains exactly its last Value & will thus continue from there on subsequent inserts...

Answer (score 0):

```
 $affectedRows = $pdo->exec("
 //HERE I do need additional code to drop column data from $databasetable similar to following
 /*------------------------------------------*/
/* I REMOVED THE SINGLE QUOTESFROM $databasetable and I was able to drop the table. Once the table was dropped then I was able to create the $databasetable which solved the problem. 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $databasetable;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `$databasetable` (
      Column names1
      Column name 2
      .
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
/*------------------------------------------*/


 LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ".$pdo->quote($csvfile)." INTO TABLE `$databasetable`
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($fieldseparator)."
 LINES TERMINATED BY ".$pdo->quote($lineseparator));
```